# Causes of a Mac's SuperDrive refusing to accept blank DVDs

Tags: macos, dvd, imac

My iMac (quad-core i7 2.93 GHz, 27") frequently refuses to accept blank DVDs when I insert them for burning.  What could be the cause of this?  The machine is just over two years old now; does dust build up in there?

OS is Mountain Lion (10.8.0).

Comment: How do you mean "accept"?

Comment: Does it reject all discs, including standard (pre recorded, not recordable / rewritable) CDs and DVDs? Or is it specifically blank DVDs that it's refusing?

Comment: @iglvzx - I mean it spins it up and down a few times and then spits it out, as if it's an invalid disc.

Comment: @Spiff - I haven't tried a regular DVD, I will do that when I have a chance in a few days.

Comment: Does this forum offer you any additional info that may be of help? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3312837?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It accepts DVDs and CDs but spat out some software disks.
A solution that worked for me was to tilt iMac backwards (at least 90°)  and then insert the disk.
This loaded fine!

Comment: Are there any forum discussions or forums you could cite confirming this is the solution others have used as well?